# How to connect to Azure pass DB from a secure network

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I would like to connect to Azure SQL server from a Window server via SSMS. In the “set server firewall” from Azure, I have given my server IP ( from the system I would like to connect). I need to know the destination IP adders of the Azure DB Server. From Azure portal the location is showing central US . To allow firewall I need to know the destination IP address.

My questions are:

```
     1. As Central US could have multiple IP addresses, do I need   to provide all IPs to my Firewall team?

      2. How can I know the destination IP address ( i.e. Azure) so that I can provide that to my firewall team?
```

Note: From SQL server management studio, the tcp default port for SQL is enabled and services are running fine.

Hope I have explained it correctly.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You cannot get a static IP address assignment for your Azure SQL Database. Moreover, what you refer (`mysqlserverdatabase.mysql.database.azure.com` designates your Azure SQL Database Server, not a single Database. This is a logical server, in which you can put up to 149 Databases (150 with the Master DB).

You have to workaround your requirement for static IP address assingment to work with the DNS Name (`mysqlserverdatabase.mysql.database.azure.com`).

Otherwise if your company firewall can't work with the DNS Name ,you need to set the server connection policy to Proxy as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connectivity-architecture) in Azure SQL Connectivity Architecture. This allows the database gateway to proxy all traffic between the client and the DB server. The gateways all have static IP addresses, which are listed in the above document.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I had gone through the URL you have provided. Sorry bit confused, Firewall team need IP address upfront (must). I need to know the destination IP address, as my Azure location is Central US , should I get these IPs from this Microsoft link and provide to Firewall team?

Comment: the problem that the ip adress is not static as i mention so azure change it every time , so you need to work with the DNS Name ,otherwise you can see the different firewall configuration to work with firewall and proxy

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup a VNet in Azure, checkout VNet Service Endpoints to connect Azure SQL.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/vnet-service-endpoints-for-azure-sql-database-now-generally-available/